# Optimize Simple SQL Query

Tags: sql

Suppose you have a table of students and a gpa. The idea is return the student or students with the highest GPA. If only 1 student, the prize is $1000. Otherwise, the amount is split between the number of students sharing the highest gpa. The result below returns what I would expect, 3 students, and an amount of 333. I'm wondering if this is the best or most optimal way of writing the query?

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    PersonID int,
    Name varchar(255),
    GPA DECIMAL(3,2)
);

INSERT INTO Test(personid, name, gpa) VALUES(1, 'Frank', 2.7)
INSERT INTO Test(personid, name, gpa) VALUES(2, 'Barb', 3.7)
INSERT INTO Test(personid, name, gpa) VALUES(3, 'Tammy', 3.7)
INSERT INTO Test(personid, name, gpa) VALUES(4, 'Edward', 3.7)

Select name, gpa,
(Select Case When Count(*) = 1 Then '1000'
 Else 1000/COUNT(*)
 End
 FROM Test
 WHERE gpa = (SELECT MAX(gpa) FROM test)
) As 'Prize Amount'
FROM Test
Where gpa = (SELECT MAX(gpa) FROM test)
```

[Results of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx93y.png)

I feel like it isn't efficient because of having to query twice. I'd like to just be able to divide by the number of rows. Something like below doesn't work (groupby issue) and adding a groupby on gpa, name would always display 1000, since each group of name/gpa has 1 record.

```
Select name, gpa,
Case When Count(*) = 1 Then '1000'
Else 1000/COUNT(*)
End As 'Prize Amount'
FROM Test
Where gpa = (SELECT MAX(gpa) FROM test)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want window functions:

```
select t.*,
       1000.0 / count(*) over ()
from t
where t.gpa = (select max(t2.gpa) from test t2);
```

With an index on `gpa`, this is probably the fastest solution.